# Type guard for interface fields on an else branch

Tags: typescript, types

```js
interface Test<T> {
    field: string | T;
}

function isString<T>(test: Test<T>): test is Test<string> {
    return typeof test.field === "string";
}

function f<T>(test: Test<T>) {
    if (isString(test)) {
        const a = test.field; // the type of a is string
    } else {
        const b = test.field; // the type of b is string | T
    }
}
```

In the above code, on the `if` branch, `a` is of type `string`, which is correct. However, on the `else` branch, `b` is of type `string | T`.

Even if I add a check for `T`, I get the same result:

```js
function isT<T>(test: Test<T>): test is Test<T> {
    return typeof test.field !== "string";
}

function f<T>(test: Test<T>) {
    if (isString(test)) {
        const a = test.field; // the type of a is string
    } else if (isT(test)) {
        const b = test.field; // the type of b is string | T
    }
}
```

What can I do not to cast `b` to a `T` explicitly, just as I don't need to cast `a` to a `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) is checking for the type of `Test<T>`, but what you want is the type of `field`.

Your branching looks like this:

```
function f<T>(test: Test<T>) {
    if (isString(test)) {
        // We have a `Test<string>`
        const a = test.field;
    } else {
        // We do not have a `Test<string>`
        const b = test.field;
    }
}
```

In the `if` branch, we have a `Test<string>`, and its `field` property is a union of `string | string` (which is just a `string`). The type looks like this:

```
interface Test<string> {
    field: string | string;
}
```

In the `else` branch, we have a `Test<SomeNonString>`, and its `field` property is a union of `string | SomeNonString`. Its type looks like this:

```
interface Test<SomeNonString> {
    field: string | SomeNonString;
}
```

In that `else` branch, we need to disambiguate, because `field` is still a union type. As long as the `Test<T>` interface defines `field` as a union type of `string | T`, we will need that subsequent test whenever `T` is not `string`.

Here is an example:

```
function isFieldString<T>(field: string | T): field is string {
    return typeof field === "string";
}

function f<T>(test: Test<T>) {
    if (isString(test)) {
        const s = test.field; // const s: string
    } else if (isFieldString(test.field)) {
        const s = test.field; // const s: string
    } else { 
        const t = test.field; // const t: T
    }
}
```